# Intel HAXM emulator UI only starts once per boot on Windows 8.1 x64

Tags: android, windows, android-emulator, haxm

I have a new machine running Win 8.1 x64, fully patched, with the latest Android SDK and Java JDK.  I installed the latest Intel HAXM package as well.  Everything fired up and worked great.  The emulator would boot in about 30 seconds and each time I'd run an app from Android studio it would start up over there pretty quickly.  But then I closed the emulator window (the UI itself showing the virtual phone).  After that, I could never get it to come up again unless I rebooted.  After a reboot it again works fine the first time, but never again after I close it.  I have tried the following:

- Running automatically from Android studio as well as launching manually from the command prompt using Intel's recommended options.  Same problem either way.
- Killing the emulator-x86.exe process, closing Android studio, unloading the Intel HAXM driver and then restarting all of that.  No luck.
- Running adb kill-server.  No luck.
- When creating the AVD I tried both the x86 and x86_64 versions, same result either way.

And yes, I have several real devices that work fine to test with.  This is just perplexing that everything works perfectly the first time, yet something is hanging around messing up any further launches until a reboot occurs.

Any ideas on what is causing this or how to go about debugging it further?

-JT

Comment: I have the same problem. Really very annoying.